# Connecting two firebase auth with one project

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm making two apps App1 & App2 which they share the same firebase database, but when user register with an email they can't register with it in App2, I got "email already exists".

How can I separate these two projects and share the the same database and the user still register with the same email in the two apps?

Comment: Are you using Firebase authentication?

Comment: Yes I am, that's what's cause the problem.

Comment: I needed an answer to this also. Setting up an app where there is a customer frontend and a management crm frontend that both should have their own list of users but both have access to the same database with different levels of privileges.

This post helped:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61286745/different-set-of-authentications-for-different-apps-in-the-same-firebase-project

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, this is working as intended.

If the apps are meant to be perceived as separate applications for the user, they should be on separate projects on Firebase.

If the apps are meant to be perceived as part of the same product, then it makes sense that the user can register in one and then log in in the other app.

Alternatively: allow the same email address to be used in multiple accounts, by setting <kbd>One account per email address</kbd> to <kbd>Allow creation of multiple accounts with the same email address</kbd> in the [Firebase Authentication console](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/fireconf-2018/authentication/providers).

Comment: I agree with you, In my case I'm in the first case so could you give me a solution for this situation ? How can I share the same database with two seperate projects ?

Comment: But if the two apps are unrelated, you shouldn't share a database. What is your reason for wanting to share a database between unrelated apps?

Comment: I gave you a solution in my answer: put them in separate projects. If you won't explain why that isn't an option, there isn't a lot more I can do.

Comment: If you want help with the code that signs the user in and shows the error, edit your question to include the [minimum code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).